# Get value of editable GridColumn in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript

I have one datgrid with no. of columns like:

```
<s:DataGrid id="cpDataGrid" dataProvider="{arrList}">
 <s:columns>
  <mx:ArrayList>
   <mx:source>
     <s:GridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" editable="false"/>
     <s:GridColumn headerText="Age" datafield="age" editable="false"/>
     <s:GridColumn headerText="Test" dataField="test" editable="false" />
     <s:GridColumn width="100" headerText="Result" dataField="result" >
  </mx:source>
  </mx:ArrayList>
 </s:columns>   
</s:DataGrid>
```

In the above datagrid result column is editable. I have make function when user done entering value in that column as following:

```
protected function onCreationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  cpDataGrid.addEventListener(GridItemEditorEvent.GRID_ITEM_EDITOR_SESSION_SAVE, onSave);               
}

private function onSave(event:GridItemEditorEvent):void
{
    var name:String = event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name;
}
```

Now, I will get name and other field value when edit end. But i need Result text. Means Whatever user entered text in that field.

Like suppose user enter **50** in result column then how can i got that value? 
Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `Result` column definition doesn't contain `dataField`?

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Sorry forget to add. I have edited. And is it compulsory to have datafield to get entered text?

Comment: If you don't specify `dataField` value doesn't have a place to be stored.

Comment: @Thank you. But no need of it now to store. I just need to check that user entered which value in the column?

Comment: `mx.DataGrid` has `DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END`, that can be used for it, but `spark.DataGrid` doesn't. Is creating custom `DataGrid` class based on `spark.DataGrid` acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Ok. I will try it out. If it helps me to solve this issue.

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For `spark.DataGrid` you need to create custom class based on `spark.DataGrid` and override method `endItemEditorSession`. In it you can access `DataGrid`'s property `itemEditorInstance`.

If you would use `mx.DataGrid`, you could use `DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END` event in combination with `itemEditorInstance` property of `DataGrid`.

```
// register listener
cpDataGrid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END, onItemEditEnd);
...
// listener
private function onItemEditEnd(event:DataGridEvent):void {
    // at this point itemEditorInstance is still available, so you can get entered value from it
    // if itemEditorInstance is TextInput
    var enteredValue:String = TextInput(cpDataGrid.itemEditorInstance).text;
}
```

Comment: I have debug but `onItemEditEnd` listener not called. I have register `ITEM_EDIT_END` on `creationComplete`.

Comment: Thank you. But i am ending it with getting with datafield value. like `event.currentTarget.selectedItem.result;` But +1 for your solution.